# Australian Skilled Independent Visa - Does working as a student count into work experience?

Tags: working-visas, australia

I'm planning to apply for an Australian Skilled Independent Visa during the years to come. The Immigration&Border protection site of the Australian Government writes that X years of work experience awards extra points for the applicant. It also notes that one has to have worked in the nominated skilled occupation or in any closely related one, at lest 20 paid hours per week.

However, it does not state whether working as a student (with the involvement of a student job agency) is acceptable. Can anyone please clear it up?

As a related question, in this situation, my 'real' employer is the student agency - that is, my salary is transferred from them and I am registered as if I was their employee - though I'm actually doing work for a separate business. (I am not sure if this is clear for everyone, this is how working as a student works in my country, it's a completely legal way, this is pretty much like a labor hire - or however it is said). So given this, who has to supply papers about my employment, the student agency or the company I'm actually working for, maybe both?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please post the link where it says 24 hours? From what I know, it was 20 hours. Whether or not your work as a student will be considered depends on the assessing body which gives you the skills assessment award. I suggest you look up which one applies to you and then study their website to understand better. Occupations and their assessing bodies can be found here: http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Work/Work/Skills-assessment-and-assessing-authorities/skilled-occupations-lists/SOL

Anyways, in your situation, you will need documents to support your claim of having worked from both the organisations. Job reference letter from the business to prove you possess those skills relevant to your chosen occupation; and payslips, tax documents, employment contract, etc. from your agency to prove paid employment.

Comment: It is indeed 20 paid hours per week, I recalled it wrong. I've corrected the question according to this, thanks for your answer.